# MVC Architecture on Grails

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

Im a beginner programmer apprentice and I was given this project to analyze how MVC works in tis grails app. There are domain(model) files, controllers and view files. I understand the basics about how model works how controller interacts between model and view. However, they wanted me to be more specific and I have some questions which I cant get the answer doing research on the web.

How does a URL map to a controller? How does the program know to go to a certain controller based off of a URL?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all in grails you have controllers and actions are made within controllers. So controllers and actions make up your URL..

For example-
If you have a website called `www.example.com` and you have a controller called `User` which will have various actions like `create`, `edit`, `show`, etc. So your URLs will be created as-

`www.example.com/user/create`

`www.example.com/user/edit`

`www.example.com/user/show`

Now first part of your question is how URL mapping is done which means if some someone wants to opens link `www.example.com` and you want him to show `www.example.com/user/create` so what you get in grails is-

Example-

```
class UrlMappings {
   static mappings = {
      "/"(redirect:"/user/create")    // <----- 1
      "/"(view:"/user/create")        // <----- 2
   }
```

Explanation-

1. Example 1 shows you that if someone tries to access your base URL("/") which is `www.example.com` he will be redirected to `www.example.com/user/create` and the URL in the address bar will actually show the redirected path i.e. `www.example.com/user/create`
2. Example 2 shows you that if someone tries to access your base URL("/") which is `www.example.com` he will be shown to `www.example.com/user/create` but the URL in the address bar will remain the base URL i.e. `www.example.com`

So I think it will help you to get started and the functionality is npt restricted to just above mentioned examples. So please visit the official documentation for in-depth knowledge.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer it was clear; I also checked out the link however, in my project's URLMappings.groovy file;                            "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
   constraints {
    controller(matches:/^((?!(api|mobile|web)).*)$/)
     }
  }   this is where I got confused

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at section "URL Mapping" from official documentation:  http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings